# Youtube direct - local server run errors

Tags: google-app-engine, youtube

After following the 'Getting Started' instructions for Youtube Direct I'm having trouble with getting the local server to run after trying lots of combinations of Eclipse, jdks and plugins. The errors below have left me more than a little confused for a couple of days now. Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
1/02/2013 11:26:00 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
01/02/2013 11:26:00 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\R\workspace\ytd\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
01/02/2013 11:26:00 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\R\workspace\ytd\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
01/02/2013 11:26:00 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\R\Documents\Eclipse EE\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.4\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\R\workspace\ytd\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
01/02/2013 11:26:01 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
01/02/2013 11:26:01 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@16614e7{/,C:\Users\R\workspace\ytd\war}: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/ytd/guice/GuiceServletConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
01/02/2013 11:26:01 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@e66f56: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/ytd/guice/GuiceServletConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
01/02/2013 11:26:01 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/ytd/guice/GuiceServletConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1101)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfiguration.java:630)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXmlConfiguration.java:368)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:289)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:205)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)
01/02/2013 11:26:01 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
01/02/2013 11:26:01 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
01/02/2013 11:26:01 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

Comment: I came here looking for a solution ;) If I find anything, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably because you are compiling against a different version of the JRE/JDK than the one you specified for your project.

RIght click your project and select Properties. Select the Java Compiler element from the treeview and make sure that "compiler compliance level" is set to the same version of the JRE/JDK you have installed on your machine and/or configured your project for.

Comment: thanks Juann, That did seem to make a difference but I'm getting some other app engine errors now. Rather than start from scratch and try to work this out I've been looking at ytd-lite which will probably suit my needs fine.

Comment: No it's a problem with finding the app engine now. But I think I made some changes when setting up ytd-lite so if I come back to this I'll repost. Thanks for the help.